# How to use babel-polyfill in the following case?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs, polyfills

This is the original code from the [Vue Webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack):

```
entry: {
  app: './src/main.js'
},
```

This is an example that I found on the Internet:

```
entry: [
  'babel-polyfill',
  './src/main.js'
],
```

However, I get this error:

```
E:\alex\vue2-project-example\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:72
                        var elements = request.replace(/^-?!+/, "").replace(/!!+/g, "!").split("!");
```

**EDIT**: This is the whole file (again it's form the Vue Webpack official template repository):

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var utils = require('./utils')
var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV
// check env & config/index.js to decide weither to enable CSS Sourcemaps for the
// various preprocessor loaders added to vue-loader at the end of this file
var cssSourceMapDev = (env === 'development' && config.dev.cssSourceMap)
var cssSourceMapProd = (env === 'production' && config.build.productionSourceMap)
var useCssSourceMap = cssSourceMapDev || cssSourceMapProd

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    app: './src/main.js'
  ],
  // entry: {
  //   app: './src/main.js'
  // },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue',
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders({ sourceMap: useCssSourceMap }),
    postcss: [
      require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You're doing it right. The problem is elsewhere, presumably in the way you declare loaders for certain files.

Answer (score 0):

try using the babel-transform runtime package: [babel-plugin-transform-runtime](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-runtime)

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-runtime
```

**.bablerc** located in the root of your project

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

you can now reset your `entry` param:

```
entry: {
  app: './src/main.js'
},
```